# Periodically this is printed to syslog - Printing DDC gathered Modelines:

Tags: xorg, xorg.conf

This is Ubuntu 18.04.1LTS installed last Thurs 16 Aug

```
apt-cache policy gdm3
gdm3:
  Installed: 3.28.2-0ubuntu1.4
  Candidate: 3.28.2-0ubuntu1.4
```

The output that started the same time as I did my upgrade from 16.04LTS to 18.04LTS.

```
Aug 23 14:58:52 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "ACR", prod id 22
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 -hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz eP)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x0.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Aug 23 14:58:53 localhost /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2309]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
```

I'm wondering if there may be a configuration setting somewhere that I can change to suppress writing this output to syslog and write to another log file as prior to the upgrade it wasn't being written to syslog. I haven't noticed but apparently there's been no Xorg.0.log or Xorg.1.log since Aug of '16.